# Nuxt3 background-image doesn't show up

Tags: html, nuxt.js

I am working on a nuxt3 project and want to use an image as the background, but I am stuck with the problem of it not showing up on my screen.

I placed my image as documented in [Nuxt3](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets).

So I tried:

```html
<template>
    <div class="custom-background-image">
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

</script>

<style scoped>
    .custom-background-image {
        background-image: url('~/assets/images/some-image.jpg');
    }
</style>
```

But there is no image showing up on my screen. Did someone ecountered the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store your images inside the `assets` folder. You can do it like this in your CSS.

`~/assets/images/background.png`

```css
.custom-background-image {
    background-image: url('~/assets/images/background.png');
}
```

But if you store your images file in a `static` or `public` folder, you can call the background image like this.

`~/public/assets/images/background-image.jpg`

```css
.custom-background-image {
    background-image: url('/assets/images/background-image.jpg');
}
```

Tested and it works.

PS: you need to add height on your `.custom-background-image` class to show the background image. e.g `height:100vh;`

Comment: Thx, I forgot to define the height :D

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the default "height=0" and "width=0" "div", if you set the style like the code below, you can see the image.

```css
<style scoped>
.custom-background-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('~/assets/images/some-image.jpg');
}
</style>
```

but if your `div` gets the content it will show the image because it will get the height and width automatically.